# Computed columns vs. JavaScript calculations, Which is better?

Tags: javascript, c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

In terms of storage and performance, is it better to make a computed column for fields that are generated based on other fields in the row? Or to just calculate these values on the client side without storing them?
And generally, where can we consider using computed columns as a good practice?

Comment: This depends on your server power, your clients average performance, the type of data etc etc.

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/252224/when-is-it-appropriate-to-do-calculations-in-front-end

Comment: Side note: Computed columns only takes storage space if they are declared as persistent.  otherwise, they are not stored but recomputed every time you use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, regardless SQL SERVER tag attached to this question.

In my opinion, you should avoid storing computed values because whenever *something* changes (a column value that was used to compute it), you have to recalculate a new value. It might be difficult to control it as there might be many ways to access data (through one application, maybe yet another one, through your database's command line, ...) which leads to database triggers (if your database supports them), as you can set them to fire whenever something changes. That's nice, but might end up with a slow response - imagine loading millions of rows - that trigger would fire for every and each of them, *calculate* that *something* and - consequentially - slow things down.

Therefore, yes - I believe that you should compute them in display layer (for example, a report).

Consider *virtual columns* whose values are derived (and not stored on a disk) - again, if your database supports them (Oracle, for example, does).

On the other hand, computed values stored in the database are OK in datawarehouses that analyze a lot of data that are *static* (don't change) so pre-computed values actually speed things up.

So, there's *pro* and *contra* for each option - it just depends on how you use it.

Comment: OK, thanks for the answer @Littlefoot
Let me give you some examples to clarify my viewpoint, in the following two examples where is it recommended to use a computed column?

1. if the computed column is based on values that never change, for example: a serial number that is generated from a combination of two other fields.
2. If the computed column is used to calculate a value that changes frequently like age.

I am not thinking about using them for more complex calculations like statistic calculations

Comment: And excuse me why did you say: "regardless SQL SERVER tag"? I am actually using SQL server and it supports computed columns.

Comment: @user842..., sorry, I couldn't respond earlier. That remark was just to emphasize that I'm not talking strictly about SQL Server (whose tag you used), but it was aimed to any RDBMS (Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server, etc.), regardless they offer any of features I mentioned.